# How might've *batare originated imitatively?

Tags: etymology, french

I was reading the etymology of French [*ébahir*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9bahir), when I lighted on this etymon.

> [Etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bayer#French)
> [of *bayer*]
>
> From [Medieval Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_Latin) *[*batare](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Latin/batare&action=edit&redlink=1)* (“to gape”), probably of imitative origin.

I don't understand how **batare* imitates gaping? I included pictures of gaping, just to affirm that we all agree the meaning of gaping.

[image]

Comment: If *ébahir* does come from *baer*, an old form of *bayer* meaning "open", you misinterpret the "imitative origin", etymologists mention an **onomatopoeic** origin, not a visual one.

Comment: *Bayer* comes from late Latin *batare* (found in a VIIth century commentary), from *bat* an onomatopoeic verb used to imitate the noise one makes when opening the mouth.
On line sources (Alain Rey *[Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Pi8wQTpjJ34C&pg=PT2441&lpg=PT2441&dq=%22Dictionnaire+Historique+de+la+langue+fran%C3%A7aise%22+bayer&source=bl&ots=mvjza8tiUv&sig=ACfU3U0D270b-wPUR4QMeXh-fHWV9QGy0w&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_qc_LqrvjAhVHBGMBHQV8BE0Q6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false), [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/bayer)...).

Comment: @Laure I was referring to onomatopoeia. I wasn't referring to visual imitation.

Answer (score 1):

What is ***batare*** doing here anyway? It appears to be modern (i.e. 1100) Latin derived from a Gallic verb.

> *batare* ME Latin, [Dufresne DuCange vol.1 p620](https://archive.org/details/glossariummediae01duca/page/620)   from Gallic battre: *Percutere, verberare;*

Dufresne DuCange then  quotes the only occurrence of *batare.* 
Here is the hapaxlegomenon from which the meaning has to be conjectured.

> The aforementioned William Correarius citizen of Lugdunum, *impegit* ( =impinged) on the aforementioned Stephen of Aigueneus, *Batavit violenter, et verberavit pro libito voluntatis.*

The dictionary continues with reference to three linguists on the meaning of  the Gallic  word **"batant."**  It might mean 'thumping,'  which would be a very good match for 'épatant' the sort of thing which leaves you open-mouthed,  or possibly it means 'on the side of the head,' the temple; or simply, 'Suddenly, rapidly, the post has arrived.'

Has there been some major discovery since Dufresne DuCange?

But to return to 'ébahir;' 
I think the etymologist quoted on **ébahir** has changed horses in mid-stream. There's a *patet* route;

> ***p***atere stands open, lies open,  and in Greek (esp, Delphic) almost identical. [Perseus L&H](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.14:823.lewisandshort)

And there's a *'hio'* route
*hĭo, āvi, ātum* 
B 2 (Acc. to I. A. 2.) To gape, with longing, wonder, or curiosity; to be eager, to long for any thing; to be amazed.
And @Laure has provided an explanation for the éba- prefix, an imitative nonsence syllable indicating a mouth gaping.

Comment: Of course there have been discoveries since Dufresne, Compte duCange. Wangle your way onto the Anglo-French research site to keep up-to-date.